# Respond to XHR calls from cache for short duration

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Within my service worker code, I respond from network-then-cache for my XHR requests. Instead, I want to respond from cache-then-network if an XHR response was cached very recently (say within last 120 seconds). How can I achieve this?

My goal is to ensure faster XHR response if a visitor action is causing same XHR to be fired again within a few minutes (since I do not anticipate these XHR responses to change in 2 minutes).

I tried to lookup if fetch api response has a header with timestamp that I can leverage but could not find one. Will I have to capture and store timestamps to achieve the above?

Comment: Caching request is usually done on the backend using the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header as a mean to notify the frontend, you can also use the [Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) to notify at which datetime the data will be updated so you can trigger a new request, which would be cleaner than a naive "fetch every 2 minutes method".

Comment: Not trying to fetch every 2 minutes. Want service worker to perform cache-then-network if user revisits a page within 2 minutes. So, seek to do cache-then-network if page visited in 2 minutes of first visit and network-then-cache otherwise. Since doing this within service worker, Cache-control http header won't resolve this (per my understanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're willing to use [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/), you could accomplish what you describe with the following runtime caching configuration:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Adjust this to match your specific API URLs.
  new RegExp('^https://example.com/api'),
  new workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'api-cache',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheExpiration.Plugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 2 * 60,
      }),
    ],
  }),
);
```

`workbox-cache-expiration` will automatically check the `Date:` header of the cached `Response`, and if it's older than the configured `maxAgeSeconds`, it will result in a cache miss, going to the network instead.

The one tricky bit is that you don't mention whether the URL you're loading is same- or cross-origin. If it's cross-origin, the `Date:` header won't be visible by default, and you need to set [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) on your remote server's response to expose it.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I'm not using workbox. But based on your snippet, leveraged response.headers.entries() to get response date from http header and handle it. Also, URLs I'm loading are same origin. However, I have handled for case where response http header may not have 'date'  due to any reason.